# Combo Box VBA Excel Using Database from Other Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping you all would be able to help me trying to get some VBA code for this kind of task. Let us say I have this in Sheet 1:

[image]

and I have the database in Sheet 2 (the file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GE-HDlfU8scnEzaVR6bjFmdXM/view?usp=drive_web)):

[image]

If I click the combo box in Sheet 1, the list COMPANY in Sheet 2 will appear. If I choose, for example USA, then cell in column CITY and ASSET VALUE will automatically change accordingly (in this case Boston and 89,826,717.71). The task becomes more difficult when I choose COMPANY that has more than one option in column CITY, for example XYZ has three options in column CITY: Seattle, Indiana, and Los Angeles.
I have read numerous articles and posts on internet but nothing seems to work. I am using Excel 2010 and would really appreciate if anyone here could offer any help.

Comment: I think it would be better if you share a sample workbook. Otherwise it will difficult for us create this scenario for coding.

Comment: @harun24hr I have edited my question as your request. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to show in city and asset value, if there exists multiple match?

Comment: @shahkalpesh If there are more than one option, I can choose one of them like Combo Box. You may add Combo Box button there if needed

Comment: @Santosh It doesn't work for multiple match

Comment: Okay so what you saying is you will have same company name twice in the Sheet2 ? if so how would you like the program or macro to return the desired result ?

Comment: @Santosh Please see my comment above your first comment

Comment: Have a look at this great tutorial that explains how to create *dynamic* validation lists (selection dropdown) using INDIRECT function http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: @EranG OK, I'll have a look

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova Do you find solution? May be I have right thing for you. If you do find solution I may help you. Let me know.

Comment: @harun24hr What I want is a VBA program for this kind of task not dynamic validation lists without programming. So, I haven't found any solution yet. If you could help, I'd appreciate it

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀[See this file by you and code by me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tcnpSY055X3F2b1k/view?usp=sharing) I hope it will work for you. Let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample file download link [Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tcnpSY055X3F2b1k/view?usp=sharing)

Codes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ctgCount, UniqueCount As Long
Dim subCategory() As String
Dim subItems As String
Dim myItems, ValidationFormula As String
Dim ArrayItemCount As Long
Dim UniqueItemMatch As Boolean

myItems = ""

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C12")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Clear
            Exit Sub
        End If

    ctgCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("C3:C22"), Target.Value) - 1
    ReDim subCategory(ctgCount)

        For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C22")
            UniqueItemMatch = False
         If cel.Value = Target.Value Then
            For i = 0 To ctgCount
                  If cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = subCategory(i) Then
                      UniqueItemMatch = True
                      Exit For
                  Else
                      UniqueItemMatch = False
                  End If
            Next i

            If UniqueItemMatch = False Then
              UniqueCount = 0
                For j = 0 To UBound(subCategory())
                    If subCategory(j) <> "" Then UniqueCount = UniqueCount + 1
                Next j
                subCategory(UniqueCount) = cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
          End If
        Next cel

        For k = 0 To UBound(subCategory())
            If subCategory(k) <> "" Then myItems = myItems & ", " & subCategory(k)
            ValidationFormula = Mid(Trim(myItems), 2, Len(Trim(myItems)) - 1)
        Next k

        Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Selection.Clear
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidationFormula
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If

'************** For 2nd sub Items ***************************************************************

      If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D3:D12")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Clear
            Exit Sub
        End If

    ctgCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("D3:D22"), Target.Value) - 1
    ReDim subCategory(ctgCount)

        For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3:D22")
            UniqueItemMatch = False
         If cel.Value = Target.Value Then
            For i = 0 To ctgCount
                  If cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = subCategory(i) Then
                      UniqueItemMatch = True
                      Exit For
                  Else
                      UniqueItemMatch = False
                  End If
            Next i

            If UniqueItemMatch = False Then
              UniqueCount = 0
                For j = 0 To UBound(subCategory())
                    If subCategory(j) <> "" Then UniqueCount = UniqueCount + 1
                Next j
                subCategory(UniqueCount) = cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
          End If
        Next cel

        For k = 0 To UBound(subCategory())
            If subCategory(k) <> "" Then myItems = myItems & ", " & subCategory(k)
            ValidationFormula = Mid(Trim(myItems), 2, Len(Trim(myItems)) - 1)
        Next k

        Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Selection.Clear
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidationFormula
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, let me check it first (+1)